# Python List comprehension - returned tuples seem to change when they are iterated and printed

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The below code is used within a class, examples of what each variable could look like are below. The expected function of the code is to split the list of users in self.users in to (as close to as possible) equal chunks, and to return a tuple of an object in self.text_list and a group of users, the number of chunks is determined by the number of texts in self.text_list.

note - python version is 3.6

I have rewritten the list comprehension at the bottom so you can run in a console to see expected outputs.

```
def split_by_text_no(self):
    user_c = self.users.count()
    print('user_c', user_c)
    text_c = len(self.text_list)
    print('text_c', text_c)
    if text_c > 1:
        divided = int(ceil(user_c/text_c))
        print('divided', divided)
        chunks = [(self.text_list[x], self.users[y:y + divided]) for x, y in enumerate(range(0, user_c, divided), 0)]
        print('multiple chunks', chunks)
        # if this is removed the users assigned in the tuple changes
        for chunk in chunks:
            print('chunk:',chunk)
            for user in chunk[1]:
                print(user.phone_number)
        # up to here
    else:
        chunks = [(self.text_list[0], self.users)]
    return chunks
```

Initially the code in the comments was not in the function, and the function was not performing as expected. If:

```
self.users = [1, 2, 3]
text_c = 2
```

the expected result of the chunks list comprehension would be:

```
[(self.text_list[0], [1, 2]), (self.text_list[1], [3])]
```

The actual result was (note the list wasn't split, user 2 is shown twice):

```
[(self.text_list[0], [1, 2]), (self.text_list[1], [2])]
```

This was shown through print statements in another function which very simply iterates through the chunks generated by the function.

To debug this I added in the code in the comments:

```
    for chunk in chunks:
        print('chunk:',chunk)
        for user in chunk[1]:
            print(user.phone_number)
```

This, surprisingly, showed that the users in each chunk had been correctly chunked. The function that iterates through the chunks and prints the users in each chunk also now showed that the users had been correctly chunked.

Can anyone shed light on why users are not being split as expected, and also why the print statements could have an effect on what is produced by the list comprehension?

To test expected outputs of the list comprehension please see below:

```
from math import ceil

users = [1, 2, 3]
user_c = len(users)
text_c = 2
divided = int(ceil(user_c/text_c))
chunks = [(print(x), users[y:y + divided]) for x, y in enumerate(range(0, user_c, divided), 0)]
```

This will produce:

```
 [(None, [1, 2]), (None, [3])]
```

However, as above, this is not what my function is producing.

I understand this is quite a large question and if any clarification is needed please ask in comments and I will adjust.

In my case this console output from the function without the code in comments

```
user_c 3
text_c 2
divided 2
multiple chunks [((UUID('c02d749b-c27f-4565-a1d2-f5c61fb46664'), 'test %FIRSTNAME%'), <QuerySet [<User: User object>, <User: User object>]>), ((UUID('2c223554-cf31-437d-84e1-d156f0d4721b'), 'test1%FIRSTNAME%'), <QuerySet [<User: User object>]>)]
chunk 0
user is 12fbc56c-93e3-49dd-8366-5e24fc4e40a0
user is fffbc56c-93e3-49dd-8366-5e24fc4e40a0
chunk 1
user is fffbc56c-93e3-49dd-8366-5e24fc4e40a0
```

as you can see the uuid of the user is the same in chunk 0 and chunk 1

this is with the code in comments

```
user_c 3
text_c 2
divided 2
multiple chunks [((UUID('c02d749b-c27f-4565-a1d2-f5c61fb46664'), 'test %FIRSTNAME%'), <QuerySet [<User: User object>, <User: User object>]>), ((UUID('2c223554-cf31-437d-84e1-d156f0d4721b'), 'test1%FIRSTNAME%'), <QuerySet [<User: User object>]>)]
((UUID('c02d749b-c27f-4565-a1d2-f5c61fb46664'), 'test %FIRSTNAME%'), <QuerySet [<User: User object>, <User: User object>]>)
12fbc56c-93e3-49dd-8366-5e24fc4e40a0
abcbc56c-93e3-49dd-8366-5e24fc4e40a0
((UUID('2c223554-cf31-437d-84e1-d156f0d4721b'), 'test1%FIRSTNAME%'), <QuerySet [<User: User object>]>)
fffbc56c-93e3-49dd-8366-5e24fc4e40a0
chunk 0
user is 12fbc56c-93e3-49dd-8366-5e24fc4e40a0
user is abcbc56c-93e3-49dd-8366-5e24fc4e40a0
chunk 1
user is fffbc56c-93e3-49dd-8366-5e24fc4e40a0
```

the uuids are all different in this case

Comment: And what was the value of `divided` in your test case?

Comment: divided  was 2 in my test case

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: using python 3.6

Comment: Can you add the console output of your split_by_text_no function call? Because I get similar result like [(self.text_list[0], [1, 2]), (self.text_list[1], [3])] with python 3.6.1

Comment: added to the question, hope it makes some sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i run your code(i'm using python 2.7)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from math import ceil
users = [1, 2, 3]
user_c = len(users)
text_c = 2
divided = int(ceil(user_c/text_c))
chunks = [(print(x), users[y:y + divided]) for x, y in enumerate(range(0, user_c, divided), 0)]
print(chunks)
```

I got

```
1
2
3
[(None, [1]), (None, [2]), (None, [3])]
```

If i changed text_c = 2.0

I got

```
0
1
[(None, [1, 2]), (None, [3])]
```

Is that what you want? If so, maybe check the divided value in your code

In order to call and test your original function, I have modified it a little

```
text_list = ['text_1', 'text_2']
users = [1, 2, 3]
def split_by_text_no():
    user_c = 3
    print('user_c', user_c)
    text_c = len(text_list)
    print('text_c', text_c)
    if text_c > 1:
        divided = int(ceil(user_c/text_c))
        print('divided', divided)
        chunks = [(text_list[x], users[y:y + divided]) for x, y in enumerate(range(0, user_c, divided), 0)]
    else:
        chunks = [(text_list[0], users)]
    return chunks
print(split_by_text_no())
```

Is it the same?
I get still

```
user_c 3
text_c 2
divided 2
[('text_1', [1, 2]), ('text_2', [3])]
```

Is it right?

Comment: In python 3.6 the result of chunks is:

[(None, [1, 2]), (None, [3])]

I will test using a float however

Comment: Ok I will try with python 3.6

Comment: it seems float types cannot be used as a step value in python 3.6, they must be integers

Comment: is the result [(None, [1, 2]), (None, [3])] right? Or you want sth else?

Comment: Yes thats the expected result, but not what i am experiencing in the function without the (seemingly unnecessary) 

        # if this is removed the users assigned in the tuple changes
        for chunk in chunks:
            print('chunk:',chunk)
            for user in chunk[1]:
                print(user.phone_number)
        # up to here

Comment: I have modified your original function to test it directly. Can you have a look?

Comment: Yes that works fine in my console, i get the same result as you - any idea what could cause my situation?

Comment: It seems you are using django?

Comment: i am yes, I wasn't sure how that could affect my function so didn't think I should mention. The users are a (sometimes sliced) query to a the User model in my app.

Comment: I would suggest to use **ordered** queryset of users(exp: order by id), if you relaying on the index. Since django sometimes uses some magic

Comment: Currently I use ordered by creation date on the query - would this be different to Id? There is a reason I order by created date..

Comment: can you have a try, in your function `users_list = list(self.users)` and use the `uses_list` instead of `self.users`?

Comment: glad to help you